# Jenkins NUnit/XUnit Test Descriptions: How do I import them into the results?

Tags: nunit, xunit, jenkins-plugins

Greetings and salutations:

I am looking for how to make sure the test descriptions that I have verified made it into the test results get shown when you click on a given test result. Example: I have a test "My_Test_One" that has a description of "This is test one". When the Jenkins user clicks on the test result and drills down to My_Test_One, they will see the description. How do I get that description into Jenkins?

I have been looking in both of the following plugins for a solution to this problem:

- Jenkins NUnit Plugin
- xUnit Plugin

After a few days of looking in the Jenkins JIRA site and many Google searches I have to admit that I am stumped. Any assistance any of you have would be appreciated.

Comment: Please state a specific question.

Comment: Edited to try and make the specific question more clear, Malenkiy_scot

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the xUnit plugin strips out the descriptions.

I'm using NUnit, and correctly have a [description attribute](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=description&r=2.5) on my tests.

My XML output from NUnit shows the description, but when XUnit aggregates my test results, it strips the description field out.

NUnit also supports [ProperyAttributes](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=property&r=2.5), but the XUnit plugin also strips these out as well.

I've also tried to use [TestCaseSourceAttributes](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) to somehow modify the name of the tests on the fly, this resulted in the tests not even showing in the test results.

As we are fairly set on using Jenkins for our test runs (as we are using it for all builds and environment maintenance) I'll be looking to take our raw NUnit XML output and make some SSRS reports out of it for testers instead.

Comment: did you eventually get the description attribute into jenkins?